# Websocket proxy on Apache connecting, but not returning data to client

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I've *almost* got a working websocket to share port 443 with both WSS and HTTPS requests via Apache's `mod_proxy` module.

The websocket client (in a browser) shakes hands, and connects.  But then **the client does not receive any data back**.

It seems like a routing issue.  Here are my `httpd.conf` settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/domain
    ServerName domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/prod-error_log
    CustomLog logs/prod-access_log common

    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On

    ProxyPass /radio wss://172.31.47.171:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse /radio wss://172.31.47.171:8082/

    ErrorDocument 403 '<h1>Unauthorized Access</h1>'
</VirtualHost>
```

And the client connects using:

```
var host = 'wss://domain.com/radio/';
socket = new WebSocket(host);
```

Finally, the socket-handling process connects on:

```
172.31.47.171:8082
```

After reading everything I can on this, it feels like this is likely an issue with `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassReverse` - but I've tried everything I can think of at this point.

The port-listening script shows a successful 'client connected' message when the browser handshakes with the port-listening script, but then just has a pending request hang forever - no data comes back.

Environment settings:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon)
Amazon Linux EC2
```

Comment: Strictly a guess, maybe to obvious to ask: do you have [`mod_proxy_wstunnel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)?

Comment: Any luck with this Jeremy?